# Using Natsort Correctly

Tags: php

I made this small script to extract names of photos from a directory.

```
<?php                     
$dirname = "newspaper_articles/nameofperson/1951-1977/";
$articlepath = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach ($articlepath as $article) {
echo basename($article,".jpg").'<br>';
}     
?>
```

The photos in the directory are named like this;

1 articletitle.jpg

2 articletitle.jpg

11 articletitle.jpg

12 articletitle.jpg

21 articletitle.jpg

22 articletitle.jpg

(Notice the sequence. I wanted php to display it on the page like that)

However my code renders it like this;

1 articletitle.jpg

11 articletitle.jpg

12 articletitle.jpg

2 articletitle.jpg

21 articletitle.jpg

22 articletitle.jpg

What I understand from PHP Manual is that I should use natsort. I'm doing it like this:

```
foreach ($articlepath as natsort($article))
```

I get an error (Warning: natsort() expects parameter 1 to be array) 
What would be your take on why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$articlepath` is array, do this way:

```
natsort($articlepath)
foreach ($articlepath as $article) {
```

Your problems is that you are trying to sort single element of array represented as a string but `natsort` only works with arrays.

Comment: I see. I thought that $article, because it was the new array (i hope this is a correct assumption), maybe it should be the one to be sorted. Your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you mate :D

Comment: Your comment clarifies the assumption. I understand. Very helpful... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to perform natsort on every element of array?

You mean:

```
natsort($articlepath)
foreach ($articlepath as $article)
```